# How to use json data in java servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets, knockout.js

I am using knockout js and want to use json data to my servlet.i want to use it in my servlet but i am not able to how to get a value of a key of json data. my json data is

```
{"data":[{"BranchId":"xzc","Name":"zxc","Description":"zxc","Template":"Template1","MetaKeyword":"zxc","MetaDescription":"zxc","MetaTitle":"zxc","EnableSearch":"No"}]}
```

My js code is

```
self.SaveBranch = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/bin/feed/currency',
        data: "BranchId="+ko.toJSON({ data: self.Branches }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
        var navTitle = result['Name'];
            alert(navTitle);
        },
        error: function (err) {
        alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
    }
    });
};
```

in my servlet i am doing

```
String BranchId =(String)request.getParameter("BranchId");
JSONWriter writer = new JSONWriter(response.getWriter());
writer.object();
        writer.key("Name").value(BranchId.name() );
        writer.endObject();
```

i want to get the BranchID and Name in my servlet. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the parameter value being JSON. There are many Java libs to do so (Google GSON, Jackson, org.json, ...). According choosen lib your code will be something like:

```java
JsObject branchId = Json.parse(request.getParameter("BranchId"));
String name = branchId.get("name");
```

*Replace `JsObject` by type provided by JSON lib, same for `.parse(...)` and `.get(...)`.*